# How do I tell if the center of a div is in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, how do I tell if the center of a div is in the viewport?

I have tried to compare the window scrolltop to the div's scrolltop + height / 2, but it did not give me the correct results.

I am wanting the vertical center.

Comment: Post the code you're using now, or a link to a http://jsfiddle.net example.

Comment: Calculate the offset not the scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, I would try using the `offset` method. Like this:

```
var loc = $('div').offset(),
    h = $('div').outerHeight(),
    w = $('div').outerWidth();

console.log((loc.left + w / 2 > 0)
      && (loc.left + w / 2 < winW)
      && (loc.top + h / 2 > 0)
      && (loc.top + h / 2 < winH)
     );
```

There's a demo in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3puJs/18/.